# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Ask Ubuntu breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  9        138
Users destroyed                                 295          0
Users deleted                                    19          0
Users contacted                                  35          0
User suspensions lifted early                     2          0
User banned from review                           0         24
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           223     31,266
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               17      5,351
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         25     38,610
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                2     13,291
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 2     45,245
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               56     35,612
Tags merged                                       4          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             8          3
Tag synonyms created                              7          0
Revisions redacted                               11          0
Questions unprotected                             0         13
Questions reopened                              117        338
Questions protected                              21        634
Questions migrated                               34         35
Questions merged                                 43          0
Questions flagged⁴                              192     37,041
Questions closed                                808     14,513
Question flags handled⁴                       1,849     35,384
Posts unlocked                                   10         21
Posts undeleted                                  98        957
Posts locked                                     52      5,447
Posts deleted⁵                                5,829     36,338
Posts bumped                                      0      8,731
Escalations to the CM team                        3          0
Comments undeleted                               83          0
Comments flagged                                  4     12,314
Comments deleted⁶                            10,219     27,302
Comment flags handled                         5,524      6,794
Bounties canceled                                 5          0
Answers flagged                                 128     21,254
Answer flags handled                         11,964      9,418
All comments on a post moved to chat            145          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...