# 2019: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
>   -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers? 
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Ask Ubuntu over the past 12 months:

```
                  Action                  Moderators Community¹
----------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  15         62
Users destroyed³                                 508          0
Users deleted                                     10          0
Users contacted                                   37          0
User suspensions lifted early                      2          0
User banned from review                            0         12
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue            153     21,742
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue                 6      3,352
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue          27     21,994
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue                 0     11,884
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue                  2     37,414
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue                50     19,947
Tags merged                                        2          0
Tag synonyms proposed                              3          5
Tag synonyms created                               7          0
Tag highlight language set                         1          0
Revisions redacted                                 4          0
Questions unprotected                              0         15
Questions reopened                                59        257
Questions protected                               84        621
Questions migrated                                38         24
Questions merged                                  15          0
Questions flagged⁵                               200     27,657
Questions closed                                 800      9,678
Question flags handled⁵                        1,708     26,141
Posts unlocked                                     8         15
Posts undeleted                                   77        674
Posts locked                                      23      4,317
Posts deleted⁶                                 5,675     32,726
Posts bumped                                       0      8,621
Escalations to the Community Manager team          3          0
Comments undeleted                                83          0
Comments flagged                                   2     14,279
Comments deleted⁷                              7,513     30,022
Comment flags handled                          3,515     10,765
Bounties canceled                                  4          0
Answers flagged                                  172     17,760
Answer flags handled                          11,917      6,028
All comments on a post moved to chat             152          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: [2018: a year in moderation](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18355/2018-a-year-in-moderation)...
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Answer (score 5):

Conclusion: moderators suck at reviewing

:D  :D :D

All the best wishes to all.

Comment: nah, they helps a lot against spammers and chat comments? And also, they don't forget that we love them :P